# Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) while installation of OpenStack

Tags: linux, cloud, openstack

I am trying to install openstack on my local machine. I am following the documentation from [devstack](http://devstack.org). The installation process breaks due to the following error:-

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

I also tried by changing

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
bind-address = localhost
```

I also tried restarting the mysql server, but still getting the same error.

Error:-

```
 + sudo mysql -uroot -pstackdb -h127.0.0.1 -e 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  
   '\''root'\''@'\''%'\'' identified by '\''stackdb'\'';'

  Configuring and starting MySQL
  ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
  ++ failed
  ++ local r=1
  +++ jobs -p
  ++ kill
  ++ set +o xtrace
  stack.sh failed: full log in /opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log.2013-04-01-164236
```

Comment: What OS are you installing it on? Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1420862/211197)? AFAIK DevStack doesn't need to have MySQL pre-installed, it should install its own.

Comment: ubuntu 12.10 32-bit. Yes tried the link you provided.

Comment: I have also edited the question with exact error that I am getting

Comment: can you do an lsof -i and confirm that mysql is bound to 127.0.0.1 / 0.0.0.0 and the right port?  can you manually connect to mysql and run queries?